# How to spoof a TCP handshake in scapy?

Tags: python, linux, tcp, scapy

I was recently trying to write a Scapy script that performs a full TCP handshake. The idea was that I connect two Qemu VMs using `-net socket` userspace interface (which seems to handle raw IP/ethernet fine) and instruct machine B to block all input from A (to prevent it from sending the RSTs). Then, I used telnet to `connect()` from machine A to B and ran the following script on machine B:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import scapy.all as scapy

filter = "port 31337"
iface = "eth0"

def prepare_response(t):
    print("Received: %s" % repr(t))
    t.src, t.dst = t.dst, t.src  # swap ethernet addresses
    ip = t.getlayer("IP")
    ip.src, ip.dst = ip.dst, ip.src
    t.dport, t.sport = t.sport, t.dport
    t.ack = t.seq
    t.ack += 1

syn = scapy.sniff(filter=filter, count=1, iface=iface)[0]
print(syn.sprintf('%TCP.flags%'))

syn_ack = syn
prepare_response(syn_ack)
syn_ack.getlayer("TCP").flags |= 0x10  # set the ACK flag
print(syn_ack.sprintf('%TCP.flags%'))

print("Sending: %s" % repr(syn_ack))
scapy.sendp(syn_ack, iface=iface, verbose=False)

ack = scapy.sniff(filter=filter, count=1, iface=iface)[0]
assert(ack.flags & 0x10)
```

The problem is that instead of receiving an ACK from A to B, I seem to get a SYN retransmission as if SYN+ACK wasn't interpreted correctly:

[image: https://imgur.com/kv7A3Hr]

tcp on machine A confirms that SYN+ACK reached the machine:

```
05:47:03.925100 IP 10.0.0.1.39634 > debian.31337: Flags [S], seq 2426802888, win 14600, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 4], length 0
05:47:03.927515 IP debian.31337 > 10.0.0.1.39634: Flags [S.], seq 2426802888, ack 2426802889, win 14600, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 4], length 0
```

Here's the PCAP file from machine B's perspective in Base64 form:

> 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

And one from A to B's perspective:

> 1MOyoQIABAAAAAAAAAAAAP//AAABAAAAVVilU9NXCABCAAAAQgAAAFJUABI0VlJUABI0VggARQAANB3bQABABgjnCgAAAQoAAAKa23pprpf6fAAAAACAAjkIFCkAAAIEBbQBAQQCAQMDBFVYpVPIYAgAQgAAAEIAAABSVAASNFZSVAASNFYIAEUAADQd20AAQAYI5woAAAIKAAABemma266X+nyul/p9gBI5CGOwAAACBAW0AQEEAgEDAwRWWKVT008IAEIAAABCAAAAUlQAEjRWUlQAEjRWCABFAAA0HdxAAEAGCOYKAAABCgAAAprbemmul/p8AAAAAIACOQgUKQAAAgQFtAEBBAIBAwMEWFilU4FfCABCAAAAQgAAAFJUABI0VlJUABI0VggARQAANB3dQABABgjlCgAAAQoAAAKa23pprpf6fAAAAACAAjkIFCkAAAIEBbQBAQQCAQMDBA==

At first I thought that this is somehow related to some Linux TCP/IP quirk, so I experimented with turning off TCP timestamps and SYN cookies. I also tried increasing IP ID, which didn't help either. Both machines are running Debian 7.5 with linux-image-3.2.0-4-686-pae under qemu 1.6.2. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a checksum issue.

In the IP layer it happens to be OK since you're just swapping the source and destination addresses, but in the TCP layer the original checksum becomes wrong when you change the flags value.

The best option is to let Scapy compute the correct checksum value for you, by adding `del(t[TCP].chksum)` in `prepare_response()`.

Comment: Wow, Wireshark didn't verify the TCP checksums for me! It works like a charm now.

Comment: Wireshark has an option to disable checksum verification because lots of stacks offload checksum calculation to hardware. You should be able to turn them on in the settings.